# EXCEPTION: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pipe.constructor') in Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, pipe, angular, remote-debugging, ionic2

My Ionic 2 application working fine on chrome browser, it gives expected output. But when it run on simulator or browser gives below error.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<label class="time">{{appointment.DateSent | date:"HH"}}:{{ appointment.DateSent| date:"mm"}}</label>
<label class="month">{{appointment.DateSent| date:"MMM"}}</label>
<label class="day">{{appointment.DateSent| date:"dd"}}</label>
<label class="year">{{appointment.DateSent| date:"yyyy"}}</label>
```

Class implementation:

```
    import {Page, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic/ionic';
    import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform, Inject, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams } from 'angular2/http';
    import {SERVER_URL, appName, alertAppName} from '../services/config';
    import {AppointmentsDetailPage} from '../appointments-detail/appointments-detail';
    import {MessagesService} from '../services/messages-service';

    var today = new Date();

    @Page({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/appointments/appointments.html',
      providers: [MessagesService]
    })
    export class AppointmentsPage implements PipeTransform {
      constructor(http: Http, nav: NavController, messagesService:MessagesService, navParams:NavParams) {
            this.http = http;
            this.messagesService = messagesService;
            this.nav = nav;

            this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');
      }

ngOnInit() {
        this.messagesService.getAppointmentList()
        .subscribe(data => {

          var appointments = new Array();
              for(var i in data){
                var key = data[i];

                appointments.push({
                  MessageID: key.MessageID,
                  CategoryID: key.CategoryID,
                  DateSent: new Date(key.DateSent),
                  Title: key.Title,
                  MessageContent: key.MessageContent,
                  Sender: key.Sender,
                  Recipient: key.Recipient,
                  DateReceived: key.DateReceived,
                  DateRead: key.DateRead,
                  Note_Direction: key.Note_Direction,
                  Viewed: key.Viewed,
                  AppointmentDateTime: key.AppointmentDateTime,
                  MessageAttachments: key.MessageAttachments
                });
              }


      this.appointments = appointments;
```

All the date pipe were working alright in Chrome browser with no error, but it gives below exception on simulator or device (took from Safari simulator debugging)

[image]

**Edited:**

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Ionic</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/mypp/">-->
  <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">-->
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link ios-href="build/css/app.ios.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link md-href="build/css/app.md.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<body>
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sasxa's answer helped me to solve this issue. Although I tried to specify path it doesn't seems to find its resource. Following resources helped me to get the answer. As Sasxa pointed out, Safari needs Intl polyfill.

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Browser_Compatibility

I tried to install it using NPM and Bower it didn't work, finally I settle with using CDN location as it worked for me.

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should load polyfills (Chrome can run Angular without them):

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Sasxa, Thank you for the help! but still it gives the error. I updated the question with my index.html file, please let me know if you seen any error in it.

Comment: Can't really tell from the code. Can you build without bundle? This way there's no way to tell where an error could be...

Comment: yes, I can build without including the bundle, actual device also its not working properly

Comment: Im using Ionic 2, how to check my path is correct in src?

Comment: It also giving error like this as well, ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl